# Howto set sequence as default value via pgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin

I have a posgreSQL database and I am using pgAdmin III to work with it.I created a sequence called primaryKeySequence.

Now I want to use this sequence as the default value for a primary key field in a table. I tried to insert

```
nextval('primaryKeySequence');
```

into the default value textfield in pgAdmin. When I click the 'OK'-button an error message comes up and says, that the sequence does not exist.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Got it. Have a look here: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/functions-sequence.html The sequencename has to be quoted like this nextval('"primaryKeySequence"') because it is not lowercase

Comment: You should change this so that your "comment" is an "answer" and then accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Have a look here: http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/functions-sequence.html The sequence name has to be quoted like this `nextval('"primaryKeySequence"')` because it is not lowercase

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is going to lowercase the identifier unless you "". So try:

nextval('primarykeysequence')

Also, you are doing it wrong. Use Serial/BigSerial instead.